# Full memory from defining a single function

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction, memory

I want to work with a function that is sum of products of HeavisideThetas. Mathematica crashes when I try to define the function. I tried this in Mathematica 9.0 and 11.2 on two different computers. In both cases, executing the line

```
f2[x_, dx_, dt_] = 
 Sum[Sum[HeavisideTheta[x + dx - n*dt/k]*
     HeavisideTheta[(n + 1)*dt/k - (x + dx)]*
     HeavisideTheta[x - dx - n*dt/k]*
     HeavisideTheta[(n + 1)*dt/k - (x - dx)]*k, {n, 0, k - 1}], {k, 1, 
   dt}]
```

starts a process in which Mathematica uses up more and more memory until the computer is all clogged up. I would like to understand why this happens and how I can get around this problem.

Comment: Use a colon: `f2[x_, dx_, dt_] := ...` and so on. This prevents Mathematica from trying to evaluate that immediately (which is not possible since the summation limits are symbolic.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What is different when using a colon?

Comment: Look up `Set` (`=`) and `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in the documentation. The difference is that `:=` will evaluated the right hand side only, if you supply arguments to `f2` (more precisely, if the pattern on the left hand side is matched). If the arguments are meaningful then Mathematica can evaluate the right hand side rather quickly. If you use `=` then Mathematica  will try to compute something for the most general case - and it will fail eventually.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher If I understand correctly, this means that after using `:=` I can compute values of f2 for numerical arguments, but `Simplify` or deriving limits would not work. Why? Is there a way I could get them to work?

Comment: Well, the long runtime and the memory consumption should tell you in this case that there is nothing to simplify. It reaaly depends on the situation. What are you about to do?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I wanted to see if one can simplify this and find nice limits when `dt -> Infinity`,`x->dt`, `x->0`, `dx->0`. I expected that if there is nothing to simplify Mathematica would simply return the original expression, rather than crash.

Comment: Seemingly, Mathematica is quite eager to chew on this... It must have been told to transform combinations of `Sums` and `HeavisideTheta` into piecewise functions. You can see it when evaluate only the interior sum...